# jQuery/javascript - Highlight for a menu when user click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi
Suppose I have a menu like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="xxx">notebook</a></li>
<li><a href="xxx">camera</a></li>
<li><a href="xxx">phone</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a menu, the menu will be highlighted, if click on another menu, this menu will be highlighted and other menu will return to original(no highlighted). Can someone give me some idea how to do it(create a listener for `<li>` or anything else)?
Thanks you

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript of what you have tried so far?

Comment: When the user clicks, will they be following the link to a new page, or do you have some Javascript catching the click and sending a background request?

Comment: @Dancrumb - a `href` can be `#id` as well ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver, a valid and pertinent point. Perhaps I should have said 'When the user clicks, will they be following the link to a new page... or not' :)

Comment: Yes, if user click on a menu, will they be following the link to a new page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way would be via [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("ul").delegate("li", "click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Then just give it some styling to match, for example:

```
.active a { color: red; }
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bk38w/), if you want a click on an already-active `<li>` to make it inactive, then change [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bk38w/1/).

Comment: Nice, but you don't really explain how to use it, like with `onLoad` or `$(document).ready()` (so +1 to charliegriefer as well)

Comment: Great Answer but for jQuery version greater than 1.7 you can use simple .on() instead of  .delegate()

    $( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a lot to go on, but assuming that's the only unordered list on the page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'ul li' ).click( function() {
            $( 'ul li' ).removeClass( 'highlight' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'highlight' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

So when any li gets clicked, the 'highlight' class (assuming there is one that does the highlighting of which you speak) gets removed from all of the li elements.  Then the one that triggered the click gets the highlight class.

Might be better to have the 'a' element actually trigger the jquery, now that I think about it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'ul li a' ).click( function() {
            $( 'ul li' ).removeClass( 'highlight' );
            $( this ).parent( 'li' ).addClass( 'highlight' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's the best I can do given the information that you've provided.